# After converting drawable to bytearray and converting byte[] to bitmap it is showing bitmap as white?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an app in which i get small icon from notification and converting it into byte[] and setting it in `imageview` result white image. How do i resolve this issue.
code:-

```
 Context remotePackageContext = null;
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    try {
        PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
        Resources resources = manager.getResourcesForApplication(pack);
        Drawable icon = resources.getDrawable(id1);
        if(icon !=null) {
            bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) icon).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        }

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Because i have to put it in Sqlite

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to convert Drawable to Bitmap right?
why dont you directly convert it, try using this:

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            if (bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
                bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                return bitmap;
            }
        }

        if (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
        } else {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        CommonUtils.firebaseCrashReport(e);
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

//Another way

```
public static Bitmap getDrawableToBitmap(Context context, int drawableId) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            drawable);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: I am using  byte[] outImage = notficationModel.getNotificationImage();
        if (outImage != null) {
            Bitmap imageStream = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(outImage , 0, outImage.length);
            holder.m_notificationImage.setImageBitmap(imageStream);
        }

Comment: but this is resulting image in full white.. color

Comment: May be your image itself is white color backggroud....or if you want to use any image from drawable folder the you can do by id of the drawable, Please see my edited ans